# SSIS connection manager cannot find my SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-connection-manager

This is my very first step in SSIS and I am trying to migrate data from an excel sheet into my database.

I am following different tutorials and I am at the point where I need to set up my destination.

Therefore through Connection Manager I try to find my database and select it.

[image]

Unfortunately nothing happens on the server name dropdown. But I use daily my SQL Server database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I typed in the server name and it was able to recognize it and populate the available databases after.

Comment: LOL thank you so much! I have the same problem and turn out I can just type the server name in